# Manipulating expressions in R

Tags: r, expression

I am looking for a way to create an expression that is the product of two given expressions. For example, suppose I have

```
e1 <- expression(a+b*x)
e2 <- expression(c+d*x)
```

Now I want to create programatically the expression `(e1)*(e2)`:

```
expression((a+b*x)*(c+d*x))
```

**Background**
I am writing a model fitting function. The model has two pieces that are user-defined. I need to be able to "handle" them separately, and then create a combined expression and "handle" it as one model. "Handling" involves taking numeric derivatives, and the `deriv` function wants expressions as an input.

Comment: As a side note:  if you are in a similar situation but do not require an `expression` for an output, create functions instead and use `body` to modify the contents of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't deal with this too often but something like this seems to be working

```
e1 <- expression(a + b*x)
e2 <- expression(c + d*x)
substitute(expression(e1*e2), list(e1 = e1[[1]], e2 = e2[[1]]))
# expression((a + b * x) * (c + d * x))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. The parentheses in `(e1)*(e2)` are not even needed - R is smart enough to put them in.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
e1 <- quote(a+b*x)   # or expression(*)[[1]]
e2 <- quote(c+d*x)
substitute(e1 * e2, list(e1=e1, e2=e2))
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted Dason's answer, which is essentially the same idea, because he answered the exact question asked, but this answer provided additional insight.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably overkill in your case, but the [`Ryacas`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/index.html) package can be nice for performing more complicated symbolic manipulations of this sort:

```
library(Ryacas)
yacas(expression(e1*e2))$text
# expression((a + b * x) * (c + d * x))
```

Also, instead of using `substitute()`, you can construct the same expression in base R like this:

```
as.expression(as.call(list(as.symbol("*"), e1[[1]], e2[[1]])))
# expression((a + b * x) * (c + d * x))
```

**Explanatory note:** One initially confusing aspect of dealing with `expression` objects is that they are really **lists** of language objects --  even when (as is often the case) those lists contain just one object.  For example, in your question, both `e1` and `e2` are length 1 lists containing a single `call` object each.

Working from the inside out, the code above:

1. Extracts the two `call` objects using `[[1]]`
2. Uses `as.call()` to constructs a new call that is the product of the two `call` objects.
3. Finally, wraps the resultant `call` back up as the `expression` object that you want.

Comment: Yeah, I tried playing with the expression as a list, but could not make it work. No wonder, this is tricky.

Comment: No doubt. It's only starting to make much sense to me after ~5 years of working with the language on the pretty regular basis. Best of luck constructing your function.